# Get aggregation for _version of documents elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get some statistics about how many documents of one index were updated using`_version` field

Unfortunately I can't get it to work with `_search` api.

My query:

```
GET /index/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "_version"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "_version": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_version",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and returns:

```
{
   "took": 2900,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 12,
      "successful": 12,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 456754855,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "_version": {
         "buckets": []
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to get that number: **how many documents have _version 1, 2 etc** like for `_version:1 doc_count:10000, _version:2  doc_count:200`

Elasticsearch_version: 1.3.7

Comment: Your query works for me. Tried it in 1.4.3.

Comment: Try with a `size` greater than 0 in `aggs`, default 10 for example. Do you get anything? `"size": 10`

Comment: @AndreiStefan Damn! I added es_version. Same result with size>0 :(

Comment: You're right, doesn't work in 1.3.7, works in 1.4.3.